# How to automatically delete stale branches in GitHub - can I do it through GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to delete stale branches that have been merged to main and have been inactive for more than seven days or the branches that have not been merged to me but have been inactive for more than three months.

Is it possible to do using a GitHub Actions workflow?

Comment: Yes that's possible. Start here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions. If you have a _specific problem_ with your workflow, that cannot be resolved through research and any existing questions, give a [mre] of that. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].